# Why do I have to run bundle install every time I vagrant ssh into my vagrant box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

I'm using a Vagrant file from late last year with a brand new rails project and for some reason, every time I `vagrant ssh` into the box, it can't find a certain gem and I have to run `bundle install`.

Below is my Vagrantfile, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "eyefodder/precise64-utf8"
  config.vm.host_name = 'myproj'

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
  # config.vm.network :forwarded_port, id: 'ssh', guest: 22, host: 2222

  config.vm.synced_folder "./puppet", "/etc/puppet"
  config.vm.synced_folder 'dotfiles', '/dotfiles'
  config.vm.synced_folder '../reports', '/reports'
  config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/app", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: [".git/", "ops/*", "reports/",  "tmp/", "log/", ".#*"]

  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
    vb.name = 'myproj'
  end

  config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'install_apt_packages.sh'
  config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'build_ruby_from_source.sh'
  config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'install_puppet_modules.sh'
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.module_path = 'puppet/modules'
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
    puppet.working_directory = "/etc/puppet"
    puppet.environment_path = "puppet/environments"
    puppet.environment = "dev"
  end

  config.trigger.before [:up, :reload], :stdout => true do
    run "mkdir -p ../reports"
    run "mkdir -p ../public/uploads"
    run "sh ./setup_guest_bash_profile.sh"
  end
end
```

**Edit**

Also seems whenever I kill my rails server I have to run `bundle install` again in order to start it up or view a rails console

Comment: where are your gems being downloaded ? and is this directory being empty again after you do `vagrant halt`  and then `vagrant up`

Comment: I'm gitignoring /vendor, I wonder if that's the source of this now that I think about it

Answer (score 1):

[`rsync`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html) is a default type with the specific property

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine
>   running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

so the changes are not reflected (in somewhat) real time, you need to force your system to sync again the files

make the change in your Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "../", "/app", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: [".git/", "ops/*", "reports/",  "tmp/", "log/", ".#*"], rsync_auto: true
```

and then after you have `vagrant up` you will need to run

```
$ vagrant rsync-auto
```

so vagrant will force rsync to sync your files when there's some change. Everything should work smoothly